# How to pass two same object from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a panel like below:
[image]

and the view code is:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">

                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                            Product Details
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>

                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-add-panel" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add new Product</a>
                                        <div id="propanel"></div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="panel panel-default template" >
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle pull-right "></span>

                                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">
                                                        New Product
                                                    </a>
                                                </h4>

                                            </div>

                                            <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobProduct.Detail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobProduct.Detail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobProduct.Detail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobProduct.UnitPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobProduct.UnitPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobProduct.UnitPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobProduct.Count, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobProduct.Count, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobProduct.Count, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

this panel maybe has one product or more.in `viewmodel` i get an object of product type.i want to create list in `view` of product inserted and pass that to controller as a list.actually i want to create list in view and add object in in it.
how can i get product inserted and send as a list to `controller`?

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your replying.i used that solution and its work but it pass correct count but null contains.do you know why?

Comment: Then your code is not correct - and you have not shown what you have done so I cannot guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Your base class:

```
public class JobProduct
{
    public string Detail{get;set;}
    public decimal UnitPrice{get;set;}
    public int Count{get;set;}
}
```

Model class:

```
public class JobList
{
    public IEnumerable<JobProduct> JobProductList { get; set; }
}
```

Pass the `JobProductList` from get method to view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.JobProductList.length; i++)
{
        <div id="collapse@(i+1)" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobProductList[i].Detail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobProductList[i].Detail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobProductList.Detail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobProductList[i].UnitPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobProductList[i].UnitPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobProductList[i].UnitPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobProductList[i].Count, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobProductList[i].Count, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobProductList[i].Count, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Your final `Create` post method should accept the enumarable list:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<JobProductlist> job)
{
    return View(job);
}
```

Comment: Why not expect the ViewModel back, instead of `IEnumerable<JobProductList>` ?